# The List :: method and covariance

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

After I solidified my understanding of why a parameter in a method is a contravariant position with SO post [scala contravariant position on method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109318/scala-contravariant-position-on-method)

I am looking at List[+A] in scala and I see this method which is fine since the parameter position is contravariant

```
def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1)
```

What I don't get is the :: method definition which seems like that would not compile

```
def ::(x: A): List[A]
```

What is going on with this method?  oh, they hide the real signature?

```
def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
```

ok, then why do they hide the real signature?

Comment: different styles of scaladoc, probably by different authors

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089746/how-to-explain-map-map-result see the comments about "scaladoc, use cases and damn lies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaladoc entries marked `[use case]` are presenting the most common cases in terms of type parameters first, often leading to a simpler construction for beginners. If you expand that, you get the full signature.

For a type `Foo[+A]`, you can implement methods that take `A`-like arguments by introducing a type parameter `B >: A`, because now you cannot provide a value that is a sub-type of `A` which would violate the type-soundness. In most cases you will prepend to a `List[A]` other elements of type `A`, therefore the doc simplification.